# ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 5 and 30 for 'Assign' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [5,5,3,30], [30,1,5,5]

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, deep-learning, keras, python-imaging-library

I am working on simple python code involving deep learning with mnist standard dataset using keras.

This is the code on which I am working:

```
import numpy
import cv2
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import backend as K
import sys
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')

img_width, img_height =28,28

def larger_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(30, (5, 5), input_shape=(3, 28, 28), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(15, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax')) #num_classes=10
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

img=cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
img=cv2.resize(img,(img_width,img_height))
model=larger_model()

model.load_weights('./mnist.h5')

arr=numpy.array(img).reshape((3,img_width,img_height)).astype('float32') #

#arr=numpy.expand_dims(arr,axis=0)
arr/=255    
prediction=model.predict(arr)[0]          #

bestClass=''
bestConf= -1

for n in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
    if prediction[n] > bestConf:
        bestClass = str[n]
        bestConf = prediction[n]

print " I think the digit is" + bestClass+ "with"+ str(bestConf*100) +"% confidence !"
```

This is the error coming up:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 39, in <module>
    model.load_weights('./mnist.h5')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 720, in load_weights
    topology.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, layers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 3048, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
    K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2183, in batch_set_value
    assign_op = x.assign(assign_placeholder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 516, in assign
    return state_ops.assign(self._variable, value, use_locking=use_locking)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/state_ops.py", line 271, in assign
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_state_ops.py", line 45, in assign
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2508, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1873, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1823, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 676, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 5 and 30 for 'Assign' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [5,5,3,30], [30,1,5,5].
```

Please help as I am stuck here for past many days.Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are trying to load model that was trained on different architecture then the one you defined, so it fails having no idea how to assign variables.